# removing some rows based on criteria - solving this by pivot tables

Tags: excel, vbscript, automation, pivot-table

i have an excel data . the 3rd collumn contains phone numbers . i have to delete rows whose phone numbers have less than 10 digits . as the data is very large and not even one mistake is acceptable. i want to use pivot tables or automation script. pivot tables is better because the number of digits is  variable and the collumn number is  variable. 
where im stuck. - whenever i use pivot tables to do this the original tabular format is lost . i get some cross tabular format which i dont want. here is the sample data.

```
date    time    number  count
1-Sep-09    15:29:44    9800000005  1
2-Sep-09    10:07:03    333333         1
3-Sep-09    9:53:46 9800000004  1
7-Sep-09    14:47:31    9800000005  1
10-Sep-09 10:51:39   9800000001 1
12-Sep-09    14:52:50 9800000002    1
13-Sep-09    8:28:28    333333          1
17-Sep-09    10:32:13    9800000001 1
18-Sep-09    9:01:42     9800000005 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think a cube or code is necessary.

Try adding a calculation to show the length of the phone number to cell `E2` with the formula

```
=len(C2)
```

(assuming that `number` appears in `C2`) - then copy this formula down to the rest of column `E`.

You can then apply an auto-filter to the table, and use a custom filter on column `E` to show all rows where the length is greater than or equal to 10.